# Streaming a file from the internet through PHP is slow

Tags: php, stream, download

I'm writing a script which will stream a file from a web address through my server to the user. In its current state it works, but it is very slow.

Here's the relevant code:

```
/* Bytes per second */
define('TRANSFER_CAP', 1048576);

/* Hard part... stream the file to the user */
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);

$file = fopen($fileLocation, 'rb');
if(!$file) {
    // TODO: handle errors
}

while(!feof($file)) {
    echo fread($file, TRANSFER_CAP / 2);
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    /* Limit the download speed by sleeping */
    usleep(500);
}
```

This script is running on my local machine. When I request the file in my browser (not going through the script) I get a solid download speed of about 2.5MB/s, which is my internets max speed. However, if I run the script and try to download the same file, I only get about 240-250KB/s.

I know it's not the script capping the transfer speed, because I have it set to 1MB/s. I also can't think of anything in this script that produces a large overhead which would slow down the speed.

Edit: Something interesting, if I do this with `readfile()` instead I get almost my full download speed:

```
readfile('http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test');
```

so it must be an issue with using `fopen` and `fread`?

Comment: is your upload speed the same as you download? in lots of places of the world they are not. you can http://speedtest.net to test.

Comment: It is not, but I'm not doing any uploading in this script. I'm simply downloading the file but for some reason it's a lot slower than if I download the file directly through my browser.

Comment: sorry misunderstood. if its not a large file try  file_get_contents() instead

Comment: your downloading cap is 515kb/0.0005s that translates to 1Gb/s. better check out [usleep()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php)

Comment: Woops, thought that was milliseconds for some reason. Thanks. Problem is still there, though :p

Comment: just to test if the problemis with fread try echo fread($file, filesize($filename));

Comment: Did you write somewhere `ob_start()`, cos using `ob_flush()`?

Comment: @DaniloKobold, I can't do that, I get a error from PHP about not being able to assign enough memory.

Comment: @qeremy I didn't originally have `ob_start()`, but after adding it I can see no change in the download speed. :(

Comment: change usleep(500); to sleep(1); and fread($file, TRANSFER_CAP / 2); to fread($file, TRANSFER_CAP);

Comment: Done, but still no change to the download speed. The reason I did that in the first place was so I didn't store 1mb of data in memory at a time, but I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I really don't think PHP is designed, or is suitable for this kind of task.

Comment: I agree with Em-Creations, I don't think PHP is the best tool for the job; can you post some more info about why you need to do this and what server environment you are running on

Comment: I don't how PHP isn't designed for this task. It's a general purpose scripting language and I'm not doing anything that's beyond its capabilities. I'm opening a URL and reading the data from a stream, that's all. I need to do this for a few reasons, one of them being to monitor how much a user is downloading. Doing it this way means I can count the bytes and produce an accurate total.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do a HTTP header redirect to the binary file itself?  That way you take the PHP out of the equation all together since all you want to do is serve up the file.

Comment: If I was going to do that I'd just link straight to the file download instead of through a PHP script. I need to do it this way for a few reasons including monitoring how much a user is downloading, doing it this way means I can "count the bytes" and get an accurate total.

Comment: Why not do an "include" of some sort from PHP to send the binary data instead of reading and sending data in chunks?  Just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're constructing a proxy server using PHP. Have you considered using mod_proxy (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) or Squid Proxy (http://www.squid-cache.org/)

Comment: That's not an option as although I am constructing what (in its basic form) is a proxy, the `$fileLocation` variable changes based on a 3rd party API call. So using a server side proxy mod won't work.